# Clarify misunderstanding about USB hosts and IRQs

Tags: linux, usb, audio, sound-card, irq

I have a long-suffering usb sound card (Creative X-Fi HD). Its manual said the following:

> Ensure that the headset/soundcard uses a USB Host that is on an individual IRQ slot. This means that no other devices in the PC can be sharing this IRQ.

- Does it mean, that I should connect only one device to the specific USB host?
- How to find out, which physical ports correspond to which USB hosts? (MB: GA-H61M-D2P-B3)
- What exactly should I check about IRQs - and how?
- What are the potential problems with IRQ misconfiguration?

Comment: Stumbled across this old question that never received an answer.  Can you update us on the status?  Ever get it solved?  Overtaken by events or do you still need an answer?